# How to re-implement matmul in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I have two matrixes A and B that I would like to dot-multiply (using tf.matmul).

How can I re-implement the standard 'matmul' so i can play with it and change functionality?

I'm trying something like this

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.tile(A), tf.tile(B)))
```

So in the future i can test stuff like reduce_mean etc...

Any clue?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have to avoid `tf.matmul` in my scenario.